# Windows Forms проблема с Transparent

Tags: c#

Я задал цвет background-а pictureBox - Transparent, и когда его перемещаю по координатам, он рвано перемещается с предыдущим фоном, и только потом меняется на настоящий. Как исправить?

Comment: Использовать WPF...